# SQLAnywhere client libraries could not be loaded

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, sqlanywhere

I have problem witch SQLAnywhere client libraries.
They no longer know what to do. I searched on the internet but to no avail.
The client is installed, the bible `libdbcapi.so` exists in the directory `/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/`.

Details:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- PHP 5.6
- Nginx

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oki.

I came to fix it.

After all, even the client updated to version 17.

Was enough only to add:

```
env[PATH] = /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64
```

File:

```
/etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Then rebooting: `php5.6-fpm.service`

And ready to work :)

[image]

Thank you for help :)

I hope it will help others.

Comment: you mean /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64 rather then bin64

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your web server executes the `/opt/sqlanywhere12/bin64/sa_config.sh` script as part of its initialization. That sets the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Hmm. Can you tell me how do this, please. I'm just start my adventure with nginx.

Comment: No, I'm afraid I can't. I know nothing about nginx.